# why their is a delay in displaying result when using scanf()

Tags: c++

Today I wrote a program in which I used scanf().  The program was correct but when I debugged it, the program was waiting for input even though I hit enter and didn't display the result until I pressed another number/character and then hit enter again.   At that moment it showed the calculated value of input.  I examined my code and found that I had placed a space after the format specifier.  When I removed the space it worked fine.

```
 `scanf("%d ",&a);`
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Your shift key is broken.  You should get it fixed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Sent a technician to fix his shift key.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I/O is [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) and you need to flush it.

With `<stdio.h>` call e.g. `fflush(NULL)` or `fflush(stdout)`. Read the [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and related man pages.

With C++ iostream do a `cout << std::flush` or `cout.flush`
(or, as commented by [jodag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790047/jodag) do a `cout << std::endl` which output a newline then flush). Read about [std::flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/flush-free/) etc..

And with `scanf("%d ",&a)` the reader has to get the non-digit character just after the number (perhaps space, or getting end-of-line or end-of-file). Read [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) man page.

I do advise flushing the stdout before your `scanf` (that is sometimes, but not always, done automatically)

BTW, the prefered C++ way of inputting a number is probably

```
 std::cin >> a;
```

Comment: It's also good to know that in c++, `std::cout << std::endl` is equivalent to `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush`

Comment: What does flushing stdout have to do with stdin expecting additional whitespace chars due to the format string he used?  There is no need to flush stdout in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is in the description of the format specifier (the Whitespace section):  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

> the function will read and ignore any whitespace characters
>   encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace
>   characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace).
>   A single whitespace in the format string validates any quantity of
>   whitespace characters extracted from the stream (including none).